# Best Approach : Azure Web Apps ( Static HTML sites )

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

For a particular customer, the IT team do not approve OneDrive and Box as source deploy repo. Box, Dropbox etc anyways is not fully supported for syncronizing using Azure functions as the API are at File events and not on folder events.

What would be the various alternatives, where customer staffs could work on 'n' static HTML sites by each BU team, deploy easily to Azure Storage using explorer or sort and how to have this update the webapp or webapp point to this Azure storage file share location ( whichever is easy and feasible )

Please suggest me any case studies or alternatives that I could explore for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> For a particular customer, the IT team do not approve OneDrive and Box as source deploy repo.

A sensible bunch.

> Please suggest me any case studies or alternatives that I could explore for this scenario.

Why not a private repo in [GitHub Business](https://github.com/business)?
It even has [drag and drop](https://github.com/blog/2105-upload-files-to-your-repositories) now (a la Dropbox).

[image: drag-and-drop]

Comment: Yes, GitHub was an option proposed but like any of us, introducing a process change, is taken with a hiccup! Let me setup a demo using GitHub, and see.

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy to Azure Storage using Storage Explorer:

http://storageexplorer.com/

Another options:

1-Write a simple c# console app that will use Azure SDK to deploy files to your Azure Storage Account. (You can use FileSystemWatcher to monitor a network folder, for example)

2-setup a CD infrasctructure using TeamCity (or any other tool), and during the after build call a script that will publish to your Azure Storage Account.

3-Take a look on Azure Files:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33258.azure-file-storage-on-premises-folder-sync.aspx

4-Use AZCopy: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/ (not sure if it has a way to detect that the file already exists and is the same on Storage Account)

5-Take a look on Sync Framework. The page is a little outdated, but it seems that there's support for Azure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt763483.aspx

Comment: Storage explorer option also was demoed, especially using a SAS URI generated. and yes, though C# is not my forte, have proposed same.  but the second option shared is not clear. Let me understand that and get back.

Comment: Ok, Storage explorer route is fine, but I would prefer to have the files /folders synced with local file system? BlobTrigger or SaaSFileTrigger got a gap of API at File level event capture only and not at folder level. Any suggestion to handle this part is more of challenge.